# Can't catch TVN_SELCHANGED

Tags: c++, mfc, treecontrol

I have a CTreeCtrl in a dialog and catch TVN_SELCHANGED messages, but execution doesn't go into handlers. What can be wrong?
My code:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMaterParamExtDlg, CDialog)
   ON_NOTIFY(TVN_ITEMCHANGING, IDC_MATERIAL_PROP_TREE, OnSelChangingTreeCtrl)
   ON_NOTIFY(TVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_MATERIAL_PROP_TREE, OnSelChangedTreeCtrl)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMaterParamExtDlg :: OnSelChangedTreeCtrl (NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    if (m_TreeCtrl != 0)
    {
        HTREEITEM treeitem = m_TreeCtrl->GetSelectedItem();
        CString treeitemtext = m_TreeCtrl->GetItemText(treeitem);

        MessageBox(treeitemtext);
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}

void CMaterParamExtDlg :: OnSelChangingTreeCtrl (NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    if (m_TreeCtrl != 0)
    {
        HTREEITEM treeitem = m_TreeCtrl->GetSelectedItem();
        CString treeitemtext = m_TreeCtrl->GetItemText(treeitem);

        MessageBox(treeitemtext);
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

I tried to use breakpoints to see if execution goes into handlers but nothing happens.

Tree Control properties:

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_MATERIAL_PROP_TREE,"SysTreeView32",TVS_HASBUTTONS 
| TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_DISABLEDRAGDROP 
| TVS_TRACKSELECT | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,4,4,115,218
```

Comment: The message map in your example doesn't contain an entry for `TVN_SELCHANGED`. Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thank you so much. I've mismatched the messages. Strange that I havn't notice it.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple.  Use TVN_SELCHANGED instead of TVN_ITEMCHANGED. Ditto for TVN_ITEMCHANGING.